# Amazon ec2 hosting server ip address

Tags: mysql, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am a beginner in linux and I need to upload my JavaEE project on Amazon Ec2 hosting. I am using putty to connect to the server and successfully installed mysql and tomcat. What I need now is to access the tomcat server i.e., http://ipaddress:8080. Can Anybody tell me how to know the ipaddress of the server to access the tomcat server installed. I have used grep --color nameserver /etc/resolv.conf to get the ipaddress but If I type http://ipaddress (from the command):8080 it says the site cannot be reached. Can anybody help me with that.

Regards,

Comment: the ec2 control panel tells you this. Either public DNS or IP Address

Comment: First, try running a local command on the server to fetch the page - like curl -O http://localhost:8080 and verifying that the application is running. Next, check the security group of the EC2 instance. Make sure port 8080 is added in the security group.

Comment: The security group needs to open the port, and to the allowable IP range (cidr)

Comment: I can see my instance in the ec2 console when I click on it in the bottom part I got the public ip address. But when I open it it still says the site cannot be reached.

Comment: I am also trying without the 8080 port

Answer (score 0):

The IP Address is similar to the below, found under Instances / Instances:

[image]

The Security Groups you have set up are Located under Network & Security / Security Groups:

[image]

Note that in the above, port 3306 can only be reached by one hard-coded IP Address, whereas port 110 is reachable from anywhere. Please also see [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

To hook a certain Security Group into a running instance, perform  that off the first screen shot, lower right.